# Is this the right way to get input for this puzzle?

Tags: java, stdin, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using this method to get input for the Spotify zipfsong puzzle: https://www.spotify.com/us/jobs/tech/zipfsong/

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fileReader() throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fileContents = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    try{                    
        String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();                
        ArrayList<String> fileRow = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(currentLine.split(" ")));
        fileContents.add(fileRow);
        int numberOfInputLines = Integer.parseInt(fileRow.get(0));
        int numberOfOutputLines = Integer.parseInt(fileRow.get(1));
        if (numberOfInputLines < numberOfOutputLines) {
            return null;
        }

        for (int lineCount = 0; lineCount < numberOfInputLines; lineCount++) {
            currentLine = scanner.nextLine();               
            fileRow = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(currentLine.split(" ")));
            fileContents.add(fileRow);                          
        }            
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Read Error");       
        return null;
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }       
    return fileContents;
}
```

So, I basically read the first line, find the number of lines to come and then read them using Scanner. Now, for some reason I keep on getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Is it because of this input method??

Comment: What is the complete stack-trace of the exception?

Comment: I don't get it when I run it. But when I submit it, I simply get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. That's it.

Comment: I believe I also asked for the stack trace in your last question (which is almost exactly like this one). It helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: @gran_profaci: You have a try-catch around almost all the code.  So it can't be any of that code.  How do you know it's even this method that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a stacktrace, it's a bit hard to narrow down the problem, but your error may result from this line:

```
int numberOfOutputLines = Integer.parseInt(fileRow.get(1));
```

Which will return that error if

```
ArrayList<String> fileRow = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(currentLine.split(" ")));
```

only results in one string. Try separating that too; assign the split line to an array first before using Arrays.asList.

This is all vague since you don't have a stacktrace to work with.